# How to format a DateTime variable to get the Month, and then put the value into a string in C#? [VS2005]

Tags: c#, datetime, visual-studio-2005, format

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text); //taken the DateTime from form
string dt1 = String.Format("Y", dt); //trying to make so that it comes to "August 2009"
```

Tried but all I get is dt1="Y".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text); //taken the DateTime from form
string dt1 = dt.ToString("MMMM yyyy")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text); //taken the DateTime from form
string dt1 = String.Format("{0:MMMM yyyy}", dt); //trying to make so that it comes to "August 2009"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have other answers that use `ToString` .. if you want to use `string.Format`, try this:

```
string dt1 = string.Format("{0:Y}", dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers will work. I just wanted to comment on the reason why your code doesn't work. [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) is designed to format more than 1 variable at the same time. You could use it, but the syntax would be:

```
string str = String.Format("{0:Y}", dt);
```

hope that helps. The format specifier you're looking for is probably "MMMM yyyy", the default format for "Y" is year-month, not month-year.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string dt1 = dt.ToString("MMMM yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dt.ToString("Y")